# How to create two slider in one page with same class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, carousel

I have two slider section with same class.
Each of them has 3 images.
But all 6 image show one by one.
How display two slider with 3 images as same time?
I can't and I don't want to change their classes.

```
<div class="abelhabil-sildeshow">
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/img_lights_wide.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/img_snow_wide.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/img_nature_wide.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="abelhabil-sildeshow">
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/img_lights_wide.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/img_snow_wide.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/img_nature_wide.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
let slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();
function showSlides() {
  let i;
  let slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
  slideIndex = 1
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 1000);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```js
function eventedSlider_(){
  
    document.querySelectorAll('.slide_container:not(.evented)')
    .forEach(function(container_){

        container_.classList.add('evented');
        let items_ = container_.querySelectorAll('.slide_item');
        if( items_.length ){
            let i = 0;
            setInterval(function(){
                items_.forEach(function(item_){ item_.classList.remove('active'); });
                items_[i].classList.add('active');
                i = i+1 < items_.length ? i+1 : 0;
            },1000);
        }
    });

}
eventedSlider_();
```

```css
.slide_item{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  margin:4px;
  background:gray;
}
.slide_item:not(.active){
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide_container">
  <div class="slide_item">a</div>
  <div class="slide_item">b</div>
  <div class="slide_item">c</div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="slide_container">
  <div class="slide_item">d</div>
  <div class="slide_item">e</div>
  <div class="slide_item">f</div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="slide_container">
  <div class="slide_item">g</div>
  <div class="slide_item">h</div>
  <div class="slide_item">i</div>
  <div class="slide_item">j</div>
  <div class="slide_item">k</div>
</div>
```